# asp RadioButtonList inside nested user control always performing full postback

Tags: webforms, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList control inside a nested user control. When one of its buttons is clicked, i want a panel to be refreshed with an ajax postback. I am using the telerik RadAjaxManager. The problem is that the list always triggers a FULL postback. markup is below

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy runat="server" ID="RadAjaxManagerPRoxy1">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnAcceptReject">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlControls" UpdatePanelRenderMode="Inline" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="btnAcceptReject" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="checkboxlist borderless" ValidationGroup="data" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="btnAcceptReject_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="The edition is hereby validated for conformity to standards" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="The edition does not meet standards and still has to be reviewed" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldAcceptReject" ControlToValidate="btnAcceptReject" runat="server" CssClass="text-error" Text="please check an option" ValidationGroup="data"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlControls">
```

I reviewed my code and markup over and over and it does not seem there's anything missing, this should run out of the box! i've been reading a lot online however about issues that controls like RadioButtonList and CheckBoxList have with ajax postbacks. does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the radio button list inside the pnlControls ajax panel. Then It should not do the postback.

Comment: I did, it does not work. on the server ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack is always true

Comment: sorry, i meant to say it always returns false